# Url not resolved on live server, working fine on local

Tags: php, yii

My site was working perfectly on localhost everything was going good. When I uploaded it to the live server it works just again except one controller (UserPersonalityController.php) 
All the controllers parsed and resolved perfectly except only one controller.
Before you answer let me tell you that
 - My controller is uploaded (Not missing)
 - I have checked by changing route but it couldn't resolved the UserPersonalityController.

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'signup' => 'Credentials/create',
            'signup/<id:\d+>' => 'User/create',

            'signup/lookingfor/<id:\d+>' => 'lookingfor/create',
            'signup/personality/<id:\w+>' => 'UserPersonality/create',
           //checked by commenting above line, still problem occurs
            'people' => 'credentials/index',
            'people/*' => 'Credentials/index',
....
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I don't know but may be it help. Did you tried it using like 'signup/personality/<id:\w+>' => 'userPersonality/create',
use user instead of User.

Comment: have you enabled rewrite engine on apache ? Either through .htaccess or your httpd.conf ?

Comment: Yes I have enabled rewrite engine. All other controllers get called correctly but this one has problem.

Comment: does it throw any kind of error or exception??

Answer (score 1):

For Url Management to work, first apache has to pass the url to yii only then yii can run the corresponding controller/action . Normally apache would process these urls as directories, and try to find corresponding files in these locations 
You can create .htaccess file like this and place it in your root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Note:** For this to work you need to have rewrite engine enabled in apache config 
You can do so with the following set of commands
In order to use mod_rewrite you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart // (Ubuntu/Debian)
```

Comment: The `service` script is available on RHEL/Fedora as well. OTOH `a2enmod` is pretty much a speciality of Debian/Ubuntu. Just saying.

Comment: Lol!.. i actually meant to say the whole thing is pretty much for debian/Ubuntu..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not solution for my problem. All Other Controllers are resolved only this is not resolved.

Comment: my apologizes, It wasn't clear from your question if this issue is relevant to only one controller or all. Sometimes I forget to change the config.php when loading classes which are in non standard locations on the server, since config.php is usually gitignored,perhaps check if it is something on that line?

Answer (score 1):

I've now answer of my question. As I have came across with the problems for several days. My local is in windows where files and directories are not case sensitive that's why it was working just fine. When I uploaded my site to the server (linux) it treats all file names and directories as case sensitive.

So controller **UserPersonalityController** was not same as **UserpersonalityController** because of the configuration of url manager in app.

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'caseSensitive' => false, //
```

The simple solution to the problem is to keep lower case names of controllers.

```
UserPersonalityController.php
UserpersonalityController.php 
//Both above files are treated as completely different ones on linux while on windows
//they are same files.
```

**Note** Never capitalize any letter between controller names. First letter and letter **C** of controller must be capital. In between never keep any letter capital as you may run into problems. There might be other solutions to the problem. But I've solved by changing file names to lower case.

Further Reading: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/651-controller-file-name-case-sensitive/

Comment: took me an hour to debug till I found your post. thanks.